# How can I separate mailboxes completely in Mavericks's Mail application?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, folders

How can I separate mailboxes completely in Mavericks's Mail application?

I don't want any of this integrated inbox/folders with the same name feature. I just want clean/separated mailboxes with their folder structures. Its nice for people who have few accounts and small number of mails. It is not a "smart feature" when you get 135,000 messages of inbox/sent/archive folders from 18 different boxes mixed in 3 folders.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think Mail.app is the program for you. I do not know of the top of my head any e-mail program that does this (well). If I had to guess though Mozilla's Thunderbird.

Comment: @AndrewU. the reason I am trying to use the native mail.app is that I have bought the macbook air 13 inch for battery life and I am thinking the more additional secondary software (read outlook) i use the more likely that the battery life will suffer. Right now with a bit of tweaking I am getting 11-13 hours out of this thing which is amazing. If I didn't have dropbox that figure would have been around 15 to 16 hours. So far the worst performing app taking around 50% of energy. I think outlook will have a significant impact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if you still have this problem, but this confused me too.

I have been using Sparrow during Mavericks. After upgrade to Yosemite I decide to give the native mail.app a try.

It looks good, but I was confused that it seem when adding multiple email accounts, it will show the structures, like folders, labels, etc in separate, but has a together inbox, which I dislike.

I believe Apple shouldn't do something this stupid (While sometimes they did...), but anyway I checked everything in the preferences but can't find a clue.

Finally, I found the way they do it....

When you adding multiple account, You still get the separate inbox and sent box and junk boxes for each account.

It is just been grouped together...looking for the small arrow at the left most of Inbox, Drafts, Sent, Junk, Trash and Archive, after expanding them, you will find your account. And you can browser them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but I have a work account that clogs up my inbox and I only need to access it occasionally. 
I disable the account when I'm not using it by going to file, preferences, accounts. Select the email account from the left and uncheck the 'enable this account' box.
When you need it again, just check the 'enable this account' box and it will reappear in the inbox list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have gotten the answered yet, but the Mail app can do what you are asking for.

If you look in the sidebar, below the integrated inbox/folders, you should see the names of your various mail accounts. Move your cursor over a name and the word "Show" should appear. Click, and you should see your account with all of it's folders listed.

Comment: No, I have tested it but not all folders show up. Also the ones that are on the top of the sidebar are still integrated so I don't see archive or inbox folders.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't like the view of Apple Mail because it's very confusing with more than one account with these accumulated top-folders for Inbox, Sent, Drafts...

I go for **Airmail** app since more than a year which completely separates the accounts and you can switch view between the single accounts and all accounts. Even in the all accounts view you can easily see which account a message belongs to. Anyway the workflow is very intuitive using gestures like swiping left/right an many other cool features, adding tags and moving to folders.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to set up a new Smart mailbox.  You can set it to "account" and if your separate one is for example exchange or gmail,  select that from the drop down menue and it will create a separate "smart" mail account.

Answer (score -1):

There is a little arrow pointing towards inbox just on the left of where it says inbox. Click the arrow and it will show each email seperated below